# SSH-Login with key does not work correctly

Tags: ssh, authentication, openssh

I got a system where I want to get access via ssh-keys to.

I created an user called `monitor` and created a file called `authorized_keys` in `/home/monitor/.ssh/` and inserted 2 public keys:

Publickey #1 is from the same host, because I want to use apt-dater; apt-dater tries to connect to localhost (monitor@localhost) with ssh-key. This does not work (asks for password)

Publickey #2 is from a remote host; the user "monitor" should connect to this host to check load and stuff.

Both public keys do not work; I can not connect from the same host (`ssh monitor@localhost` or from the other server with `ssh monitor@example.com`).

`Error: debug1: Roaming not allowed by server`

What can I do here?

Answer (score 1):

The message `Error: debug1: Roaming not allowed by server` is only a debug message, not more.

---

Follow the steps below to authenticate via public key:

**On your server** enable the password authentication. Open the ssh-server configuration

```
 sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and enable the password authentication

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Reload the configuration

```
sudo service ssh reload
```

---

**On your client**

Copy your public key via `ssh-copy-id`

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -p 22 user@server
```

or as alternative

```
cat id_rsa.pub | ssh server cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

---

**On your server**

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and disable the password authentication

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Reload the configuration

```
sudo service ssh reload
```

Comment: To avoid a pitfall like this in the future try looking at the variable $? Which if not 0 (according to standards) means the previous command failed

Comment: @MyFault Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)